# Create pdf from dynamic data using mpdf

Tags: php, mpdf

There is a template file **Template.php**

with the following content

```
<h1>Welcome <?php
                 echo $_REQUEST['name'];
            ?>
</h1>
```

I want to generate pdf using the [mpdf](https://github.com/mpdf/) library (latest version)

The only way described in there documentation is to use `WriteHTML()` method

So what I am trying

```
$content = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . "/template.php");

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
    'tempDir' => __DIR__ . '/template/'
]);

$mpdf->WriteHTML($content);
$mpdf->Output();
```

But how can I send some get request to generate the name dynamically?

Comment: Do you want to save pdf file with some custom name?

Comment: Yes, but that's something else, first I want to generate it with dynamic data

Comment: You can use simple html content to generate pdf file.

Comment: Then how can I put different names there?

Comment: Html can be generated with dynamic content as well.

Comment: It looks like you are talking beyond the scope of my problem, I can only send GET request to a template to generate the pdf.

Comment: It is not really clear what is the problem here. Lovepreet Singh is correct that you can insert any dynamic code into your HTML. Using GET is bad idea since some browsers cut off everything beyong e.g. 1000 characters (previously IE). Also you should first validate user input, not embed global variable directly into HTML. You may want to rephrase your question to make it clearer or find some MPDF examples.

Comment: You just wanna print hellow "username" as pdf?

Comment: Sorry @lubosdz, but really I am not getting you. The limit or security of get request is not the issue here. In clear words, I have a php file which can produce html content (template.php) and I just want to print the output in a pdf file using mpdf library. I hope this explanation makes some sense. :)

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile . Not really. I have a complicated template with several $_REQUEST variables, just to keep the problem simple, I presented it that way. If I can get the solution to how to print one variable dynamically, I will be able to do it for all other.